# Trouble installing lxml with custom install location for libxml2/libxslt

Tags: rhel, software-installation, directory, python, non-root-user

I am attempting to install a python module called `lxml` to my account on a supercomputer running RHEL.

I do **NOT** have root access or super user status.

`lxml` requires the dev/devel versions of `libxml2` and `libxslt`, because they include header files that `lxml` needs to build. But the supercomputer has the non-dev versions installed to its root `/usr` directories, so I installed the dev versions to my `home` directory by building them from source.

Both built smoothly without throwing any errors, and all of the necessary header files are in `$HOME/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml`, etc.

However, whenever I try to `pip install lxml`, it tries to use the non-dev `libxml2` & `libxslt` in the root `/bin`:

```
[myusername@q0144 ~]$ pip install --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/python_modules" lxml
... (some unimportant messages) ...
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/local/lib
building 'lxml.etree' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_myusername/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/N/soft/rhel6/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:346:
/tmp/pip_build_myusername/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:31: error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/pip_build_myusername/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:11:4: error: #error the development package of libxml2 (header files etc.) is not installed correctly
...(many more lines saying that the headers are missing, etc.)
```

And there's several dozen more lines saying that the development packages aren't installed correctly, since it's looking at the wrong ones.

How do I get the system to use the versions of `libxml2`/`libxslt` that I installed?

I even source my `$HOME/bin`, `$HOME/usr`, etc. directories first in `.cshrc`.

Just to make sure to cover all my bases, I also tried building `lxml` from source, following the directions in the `build.txt` document included in the source tarball:

```
[myusername@q0144 lxml-3.3.5]$ python setup.py build_ext -i -I $HOME/usr/include/libxml2/libxml --without-cython --with-xslt-config=$HOME/usr/local/bin/xslt-config
Building lxml version 3.3.5.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/local/lib
/N/soft/rhel6/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
warnings.warn(msg)
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/N/hd00/myusername/Quarry/python_modules/lxml-3.3.5/src/lxml/includes -I/N/u/myusername/Quarry/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -I/N/soft/rhel6/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:346:0:
/N/hd00/rccaton/Quarry/python_modules/lxml-3.3.5/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:
13:32: fatal error: libxslt/xsltconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I basically get the same problem with it looking at `/user/local/lib` instead of my `$HOME/user` etc. directories.

How do I get around this?

Comment: I think you can modify setup.py as necessary to look at the correct paths. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/16984753/350713

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `bin` subdirectories of both packages (libxml2/libxslt) are on your `PATH`. They contain `*-config` scripts which are used during compilation of lxml to find out where libxml2/libxslt were installed.

```
[pdobrogost@host /]$ echo $PATH
(...):/opt/libxslt-1.1.27/bin:/opt/libxml2-2.6.32/bin:(...)
[pdobrogost@host /]$ which xml2-config && which xslt-config
/opt/libxml2-2.6.32/bin/xml2-config
/opt/libxslt-1.1.27/bin/xslt-config
```